# Google App Script Search and Update Single Cell Value Across Multiple Sheets If Found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

How to search cell value across multiple google sheet like 20 sheets and if found update that value. For example, on the 17th Sheet (it can be any sheet, it must be dynamic), there is a certain value that I need to search, how I gonna do that? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the class [`TextFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) and method [`createTextFinder()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext) on a [`Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). Additionally use [`getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) to get all sheets of a given spreadsheet.

Here a function that will search and replace all occurences of a given string with another given string.

```js
/**
 * Search and replace a string with another string.
 * @param {string} searchTerm term to search for in all sheets
 * @param {string} replaceTerm term to replace all occurences of the search term with
 * @returns number of occurrences replaced
 */
function searchAndReplaceAllSheets(searchTerm, replaceTerm) {
  // get all sheets in your Spreadsheet
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  let totalReplaced = 0;
  // Loop over all sheets
  sheets.forEach((sheet) => {
    // create instance of TextFinder
    const noReplacedElements = sheet
      .createTextFinder(searchTerm) // create text finder
      .matchCase(false) // case-insensitive
      .replaceAllWith(replaceTerm); // replace-all values that contain the search term with the new value
    totalReplaced += noReplacedElements;
  });
  Logger.log(
    `Replaced ${totalReplaced} occurences of ${searchTerm} with ${replaceTerm} in ${sheets.length} sheets`
  );
  return totalReplaced;
}
```

> Note: I did not test this, but this should work.

Comment: I will try this and let you know once it is sucessful. Thank you @Mushroomator